# VueJS how to loop with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, vuejs2

In my `vue`-application I have an Iframe where I want to find, for example all `<b>`-elements and replace them with `<span style="font-weight:bold">`

So I tried to do this:

```
saveContent() {
   const html = document.getElementById("myIframe").contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;

   $(html).find("b").each(function() {
      $(this).replace('<span style="font-weight:bold">');
   });
}
```

but when I do this, I get the error: `Error in v-on handler: "Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression...`

I guess it has something to do with using `jquery` with `vue` together?!

How can I solve this and maybe also search and replace all `<i>` and `<u>`-tags?

Comment: This won't answer your question but I'd recommend not using Vue and Jquery together. They are completely different. You can read about it here: https://www.quora.com/How-bad-is-it-to-use-jQuery-with-Vue. I haven't used VueJS a lot myself so I don't know how to do what you want in Vue. But I recommend creating a new question here on SO and asking how to do the above in VueJS.

Comment: May I asked you why would you like to loop through jQuery while using Vue? [Why not loop through the array with Vue](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) instead?

Comment: @ManuelAbascal I'm not looping through an array...

Comment: Are you sure `$` is the jQuery object? Did you try `jQuery(html)...`

Comment: Add more code, where and when you import $, when you use `saveContent`, how to instantiate the Vue component.